# Use Quill insertText in react-quill Using react-quill

Tags: reactjs, next.js, quill, react-quill, react-quilljs

I'm trying to use the quill insert text method, but its not working for react quill.(next.js react)

my code

```
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });
const { Quill } = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });

Quill.insertText('memes');
```